# Tensorflow Cost equals to None

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a neural network with two hidden layers of 6 nodes each and input with 11 nodes and one output(binary classification):

```
L1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W1) + b1)
L2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(L1, W2) + b2)
hy = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(L2, W3) + b3)
```

My cost function defined as following, where y is a placeholder:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-Y * tf.log(hy) - (1 - Y) * tf.log(1 - hy))
```

My optimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

It seems that everything is defined well, but I'm still getting a none value of cost function when I run it in the session.

My session:

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: y_train})
```

Comment: Try `print(sess.run([cost,optimizer], feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: y_train})[0])`

Comment: i got same result  :(

Comment: Can you give a reproduce example ?

Comment: well i have debuged the code i find out that the problems was in the weights and not the loss itself the weights befor run the sess.init they were good  but once i do it they all turns to nan , any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Calling **sess.run** on optimizer(what you are doing), is expected to give **None** because this operation does not result in any value rather it applies in order to minimize the value of the cost function, in other words, optimize it.

In order to print cost, your code should be:

```
sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: y_train})[1]
```